# ffmpeg: how to extract keyframes from certain time ranges into filenames with timestamps from the original video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, codec

I have as input specific timestamps I'm interested in, and I wish to extract keyframes closest to them. I thus use `skip_frame nokey` and a `select='between(t,...,...)+between(t,...,...)+...'` where I add a few seconds around each time I'm interested in (enough so that at least one keyframe will fall in that range based on the input video I have, and then can manually delete if more than one came out in a given time range in my sequence). Chaining the `between()`s lets me use a single command to extract all of these images in order to avoid seeking from the beginning of the video for each image, were I to use separate command per image. So this part works fine.

The problem is that I want the output image filenames to correspond to the timestamps, in seconds (or some decimal fraction of seconds like tenths or milliseconds) of the extracted frames with respect to the INPUT video. With older versions of ffmpeg, I used to be able for example to get output filenames being times in terms of tenths of a second with `-vsync 0 -r 10 -frame_pts true %05d.webp` but with recent versions, that results in the error `One of -r/-fpsmax was specified together a non-CFR -vsync/-fps_mode. This is contradictory.` Replacing the deprecated `-vsync` with `-fps_mode` and one of the CFR values results in ffmpeg DUPLICATING frames to fulfill the specified `-r` value which results in a huge number of output images. The way I am able to get just the set of keyframes I want and no duplications is to drop the `-r` and use `-fps_mode passthrough`, but then I lose the naming of the output files by their time in the original video. Searching around here and elsewhere on the web, I have tried things like setting `settb=...,setpts=...` and `-copyts` but in the end couldn't get it to work.

As a complete example, the command
`ffmpeg -skip_frame nokey -i "input.mp4" -vf "select='between(t,15,25)+between(t,40,50)+between(t,95,105)+between(t,120,130)+between(t,190,200)',scale='min(480,iw)':-2:flags=lanczos" -fps_mode passthrough -copyts -c:v libwebp -quality 75 -preset photo -frame_pts true %05d.webp` gives me the right set of output images, but not the filenames that would make it easy for me to quickly manually find frames corresponding to specific times in the original video.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of setting `-r` was to indirectly set the codec time base.

Recently, `-r` behaviour was changed so as to always produce CFR streams.

So, just set codec time base directly: `-copyts -fps_mode passthrough -enc_time_base 1/10 -frame_pts true` where its value is the reciprocal of framerate.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you can use the pts filter to rename the frames based on their timestamps?

You might be able to use `setpts='PTS-STARTPTS'` filter to reset timestamps and `showinfo` filter to print information about each frame to `stderr` and `command 2>&1 | grep showinfo | grep pts_time:[0-9.]* -o | grep [0-9.]* -o > timestamps.txt` to pipe ffmpeg's `stderr` to `stdout`, filtering out the lines containing timestamps information and saves them into a text file. This will give a list of timestamps for each frame in timestamps.txt. The only issue here is that the frames are not named by their timestamps directly, but you have an ordered list of their timestamps corresponding to the order of frames.

Maybe something like this?

```
ffmpeg -skip_frame nokey -i "input.mp4" -vf "select='between(t,15,25)+between(t,40,50)+between(t,95,105)+between(t,120,130)+between(t,190,200)',scale='min(480,iw)':-2:flags=lanczos, setpts='PTS-STARTPTS', showinfo" -fps_mode passthrough -copyts -c:v libwebp -quality 75 -preset photo -frame_pts true frame%05d.webp 2>&1 | grep showinfo | grep pts_time:[0-9.]* -o | grep [0-9.]* -o > timestamps.txt
```

Now, you just have to rename the frames with their corresponding timestamps, with something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
while read line
do
   mv -i -- "frame$(printf %05d $i).webp" "$line.webp"
   let i++
done < timestamps.txt
```

But, it's gonna be slow and not super accurate because of the nature of encoding. Keyframes serve as a reference for other frames, and aren't necessarily generated at regular intervals. If you need to have images that correspond to exact times, you may want to reconsider whether you need to only export keyframes, which will bloat the MP4 or play around with encoding.